# How to do delegated authentication in salesforce

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, federated-authentication, delegated-authentication

I am implementing SSO, the documents which are avaliable via Salesforce.com are hard to understand. Does anybody know an easy to understand document or blog where I can study and implement it. Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 4):

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com

Refer the above article and thats the one of the best articles i have read on this .

You will first need to raise a case with salesforce to enable delegated authentication for your org.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_delauthentication_configuring.htm&language=en

Not sure if you referred the above link to configure this .

Its a very simple process where once salesforce enables the delegated authentication for your org you will follow the below steps

> 1)In Salesforce, download the Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file AuthenticationService.wsdl from Setup by clicking Develop | API | Download Delegated Authentication WSDL
>
> 2)Add a link to your corporate intranet or other internally-accessible site that takes the authenticated user’s credentials and passes them through an HTTP POST to the Salesforce login page.
>   Because Salesforce does not use the password field other than to pass it back to you, you do not need to send a password in this field.
>
> 3)In Salesforce, specify your organization’s single sign-on gateway URL from Setup by clicking Security Controls | Single Sign-On Settings | Edit. Enter the URL in the Delegated Gateway URL text box.
>
> 4)For security reasons, Salesforce restricts the outbound ports you may specify to one of the following:
>   80: This port only accepts HTTP connections.
>   443: This port only accepts HTTPS connections.
>   1024–66535 (inclusive): These ports accept HTTP or HTTPS connections.
>
> 5)https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_delauthentication.htm&language=en

Read the above document to understand the flow

[image]

Comment: Can you explain step 2 and 3 how to get the link to corporate intranet? can I put any address? is that url has to have some functionality?

Comment: The url you use must call login() method of salesforce.Say you have a .NET site and your aspx page should intitiate salesforce login() method .